# Como puedo imprimir multiples Imagenes con Vue carousel-3d?

Tags: html, vue.js

Estoy utilizando vue.js y vue carousel-3d para mostrar imagenes de una API, sin embargo cuando sigo el ejemplo de la web oficial( https://wlada.github.io/vue-carousel-3d/examples/ )solo me imprime la primera image y manda un error de error en la terminal esto es el codigo que estoy utilizando:

solicitud a la API:

```
<script>
export default {
  data: {
    videos_p: []
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("xxxxxxxxx")
      .then(response => {
        this.videos_p = response.data
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

y esto es como llamo el carousel 3-d para la vista:

```
<carousel-3d :disable3d="true" :space="365" :clickable="false" :controls-visible="true" :autoplay="true" :autoplay-timeout="4500">
    <slide v-for="(slide, i) in videos_p" :index="i">
      <img v-bind:src="slide.image_url" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        nota
      </figcaption>
   </slide>
</carousel-3d>
```

este es el mensaje que e arroja desde el inspector del navegador :

"./~/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-3fef4902"}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./app/javascript/packs/content/playlist.vue
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) : component lists rendered with v-for should have explicit keys. See https://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#key for more info.
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/content/playlist.vue 6:2-193
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 ./app/javascript/packs/content/playlist.vue"

y este es la unica imagen que me envia :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: debes añadir al lado de `v-for` el key que seria algo como esto `:key="i"` y listo

Comment: Entonces reemplazo el :index="i" por el :key="i"??????

Comment: intenta haciendolo a ver como te va